# How to replace new line character with csv newline character

Tags: c#, regex, csv

I need to import a multi-line string into a single cell of CSV

```
string message = "This is 1st string.
                  This is 2nd string.
                  This is 3rd string."
```

When I try to import string into CSV it splits up in multiple rows.
If I remove new line chars from "message" the string is added as single line.
I need to add message as it is into a single cell (multi-line into single cell).

I tried following codes:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\r\n?|\t", RegexOptions.Compiled);    
message= regex.Replace(message, String.Empty);
char lf = (char)10;
message= message.Replace("\n", lf.ToString());
```

But the message is added to multiple rows in CSV.

Comment: When you say "CSV newline character", it makes it sound as if you think there's some dedicated newline character used for CSV files, to make a distinction from the regular system newline character(s)? Such a character doesn't exist. Decent CSV readers will recognise that a text field starts with " and be able to detect newlines within the boundaries of the cell and treat them as part of the cell.

Comment: Well, "CSV" stands for "comma separated values". Since your text does not contain commas, it should end up in the same cell if you choose e.g. a comma as the divider. To be more concrete: You do not specify how you determine " message is added to multiple rows in CSV". Presumably you import it in Excel? Then take a look at the options in Excel's import dialogue. Alternatively, you could explore how to create *a true Excel file* from within your program; then you can split your data any way you like. .net interacts well with MS Office.

Comment: [Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bd6c67/how-to-create-excel-file-using-C-Sharp/) is an example if you have MS Office installed. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/how-do-i-create-an-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-in-c-sharp-without-installing-mic) is an example to create an Excel file with an open source library. If you want to create an Open Document Format file, which is probably a good idea for simple spreadsheets, take a look at AODL. [Here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/AODL_example_1) is a simple example.

Comment: In order to receive more helpful answers I suggest you specify your workflow. In particular: 1. How can the data look? Which whitespace and other special characters, commas, semicolons etc. can it contain? 2. How do you process or open the resulting CSV file?

Comment: Try `.Replace("\n", "\r")` to replace all LF with CR.

Comment: Try the reverse to see what is wanted. Create an Excel sheet containing one cell which has those three lines. Export that sheet as a CSV. Close Excel. Open that exported CSV in Excel and check that it loads as required. Then build your new CSV in the same style.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to remove the br tag (with <> ) in case it contains html, and maybe you can replace like:

.Replace(br tag between <>,"");

.Replace(Enviroment.NewLine,"");

And I´m not sure if the regex would replace one by one, but try this:

.Replace("\r","")

ant then:

.Replace("\n","")

Hope it works

Answer (score -3):

Using `\r\n?|\t`, you replace each carriage return, possibly followed by a line feed, but also every tab (the `|\t` means '*or a tab*')

I guess you probably want to replace `\r\n?\t*`, i.e. a carriage return, possibly followed by a line feed, followed by an undetermined number of tabs, and then replace this whole block.